# Beego Redirect with Post method

Tags: go, beego

I want to redirect the url using the POST method.

The code is usually using `this.Redirect("/", 302)`.

This time, I want something like post url which should redirect to that page.

Is this possible with Beego?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Beego's `Redirect` takes a http code, you're just using the wrong one. You want `307` to force the request method to be the same as the original one.

```
this.Redirect("/", 307)
```

Most clients and browsers issue a `GET` on the 302 target, which was actually contrary to the RFC.

Due to this, [303 and 307](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection) were introduced:

- 303: clients **must** use a `GET` request
- 307: clients **must** use the original method (eg: `POST` if a `POST` was originally used)

Comment: Thanks for info. This will be help a lot. how can i pass query values here? like how can i set the parameters to be passed?

Comment: You don't. A 307 means the client will retry exactly the same operation on the redirect URL.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer here. It is amazing how I missed this after so many years of web development. Will be reading docs/specs more often. Thanks!